# Commonly used Error Correcting Codes

Tags: computer-architecture, error-correcting-codes

We know error correcting codes are parameterized as (n,k,d) codes. I wanted to know the values of these parameters for some commonly used error correcting codes in computer memories or in DRAMs, etc.

I just wanted to see some values for these parameters, used in real life applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure this greatly varies according to the application and the specific code in use.

Though not for DRAMs, maybe this will give you some insights:

> For CDs encoding, a (28,24)-Reed Solomon code is used.
>   For DVDs, it is a (208,194)-Reed Solomon code.

Symbols are over $GF(2^8)$, that is, 8 bits per symbol.  The notation is $(n,k)$-ReedSolomon for a linear $[n,k,d]$ code ($k$ being the dimension). RS is an [MDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDS_code) code and has $d=n-k+1$.

(I think this was the source, but maybe you can find it online):
*Stephan Wicker and Vijay Bhargava (eds.), **Reed-Solomon Codes and their Applications**, IEEE Press, 1994*

Comment: Actually, CDs use _two_ Reed-Solomon codes --  $(32,28)$ code and a $(28,24)$ code -- in what is called  a _cross-interleaved_ design for error-correction. There is also another code which converts the bits of these Reed-Solomon codewords into the bits that are actually recorded as pits or non-pits on the disc itself. The Wicker and Bhargava book has lots more details.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for Memories, try google  **ECC memories**. It seems that the main trend is to correct a single bitflip per memory address. For that purpose a distanse of $d=3$ is enough and a Hamming code can be used.

- [Here](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=parameters%20of%20ecc%20memories&source=web&cd=23&ved=0CCoQFjACOBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amd.com%2Fus%2FDocuments%2F47644A_ecc_embedded.pdf&ei=S0KXUPzUE8n5iwKqzIGQBA&usg=AFQjCNGLJ2Q_ITH8-2LHlUZXFtXIjA19iw&cad=rja) is an AMD memory, where each 64 bits are encoded via Hamming code ($d=3$, fixing a single bit flip).
- TI's [TMSx70](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=parameters%20of%20ecc%20memories&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&ved=0CFYQFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Fgeneral%2Fdocs%2Flit%2Fgetliterature.tsp%3FliteratureNumber%3Dspna126%26fileType%3Dpdf&ei=lkGXUOnuBYmQiAK2nIGYBQ&usg=AFQjCNElQnIU-NOnR6BR-8DS4Y9j9mBS1w) controller, uses a modified Hamming code which corrects up to one error but detects up to two errors (SECDED -single error correction and double error detection). If I read it correctly, they add 8 bits to any 128bit code.